# Arduino and solenoid with a single power supply

Tags: power-supply, arduino, relay, solenoid

I am trying to create a small project involving controlling a solenoid via an Arduino Uno clone with a single power source.

I currently have it set up to power the Arduino with a power adapter rated for its purpose while the solenoid is powered by a higher voltage battery. They are connected together through a relay switch.

My goal is to have a single power adapter be able to power both devices. I'm not sure what the correct method would be to do this properly, safely, and inexpensively.

Listings from Amazon of my equipment:

- **Arduino**: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EWOE0UU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EWOE0UU)
- **Relay**: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LW15A4W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LW15A4W)
- **Solenoid**: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VC6R4DH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VC6R4DH)

All my knowledge on this comes from reading these forums and watching videos so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Considerations for powering solenoid and arduino from the same power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/considerations-for-powering-solenoid-and-arduino-from-the-same-power-supply)

Answer (score 1):

Your Arduino can run off of 12V, which is what your solenoid is rated for.  The relays appear to be 5V.  I don't know what the current draw on your relay coils are, but running the solenoid off of 12V and stepping that down to 5V with either a DC/DC or linear regulator is probably the easiest (vice bumping 5V up to 12V).  I would be on the lookout for voltage spikes on both rails when switching.

Answer (score 0):

The arduino has a barrel connector with a linear regulator that accepts 12V and regulates it down to 5V. Of course as your current on the 5V rail increases the power wasted by the regulator adds up. If you are only powering the arduino and that SRD relay (~85mA) then you will be fine there.

The arduino has some basic filtering on that input and the linear regulator helps, but if you see the arduino resetting when you trigger the solenoid you may have to add some filtering. Cross that road if you get to it.

The relay is convenient but probably unnecessary. You could drive that solenoid with a transistor or mosfet.